# File extension match in python using RegexMatchingEventHandler

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, observer-pattern, python-watchdog

I want to apply basic pattern match on the file extension (.gz) using both `RegexMatchingEventHandler` and `re`.

I am getting `.gz` and `.gz.tmp` files in my input directory and I only want to pick `.gz` files.

I tried using `(.)*.gz$` and similar patterns but they are not working with `RegexMatchingEventHandler`.
Please help me with a pattern which works for both `RegexMatchingEventHandler` and `re`.

Answer (score 1):

`/.*\.gz/` should work with your situation, you didn't escape the '.' in '.gz'.